# Adding active listener to AbstractDecoratedTextEditor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a editor `MyEditor` that extends `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor`.
In eclipse, I can have a lot of files of `MyEditor` opened. Each file is a instance of `MyEditor`.
When I click in the tab to change the file, I need to execute same actions of the instance (file) that will open.
That is, I need to add a listener in `MyEditor` to know when the instance (file) became active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener` to listen for changes to parts.

```
IPartService partService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();

partService.addPartListener(listener);
```

The

```
public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPart part)
```

method of the listener will be called when a part is activated so you check here for your editor.

Your editor is an instance of `IWorkbenchPart` so you in the `partActivated you can just use

```
if (part instanceof MyEditor)
 {
   MyEditor editor = (MyEditor)part;

   ... check which file this editor is editing 
   ... and do action if it is the required file

 }
```

Comment: Im trying to addPartListener on the initializeEditor method of AbstractDecoratedTextEditor. But when some file become active, all files fires the partActivated. For example, if I have 4 files opned in MyEditor, and 1 file become active, the partActivated was executed 4 times, one per file. Am I doing something wrong? Thx

Comment: If you have four editors open all listening with their own IPartListener you will get four calls to partActivated. If you just want one call you need to arrange that the listener is only added once.

Comment: If I only add listener for file1.txt and open it on MyEditor, the partActivated was executed to file1.txt. But If i open file2.txt and file3.txt without listener in MyEditor, the listener of file1.txt always executed, even if file1.txt was not activated.

Maybe I need to add listenner for all, but need to check inside partActivated if the file is really active. But how? Thx

Comment: The listener is called when any part is activated not just your particular editor part. The `IWorkbenchPart part` parameter of `partActivated` tells you which part is being activated.

Comment: Now I understood. But I need execute an action just to the instance (file) that will open. It can be possible using PartListener? Or using another listener? Thx

Comment: I added an outline of the code you need to use in the listener to the answer

Comment: Now, it works using this code:

if (part instanceof MyEditor && part.equals(MyEditor.this))